# Принцип работы метода Sort

Tags: массивы, ruby, сортировка

Использую метод Sort для сортировки элементов массива, полученных из ввода пользователем. В моем методе alphabetize я вывожу элементы массива либо по возрастанию, либо по убыванию используя метод Sort. Код вот такой:

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
arr.sort!
if rev==true
    arr.reverse!
end
return arr 
end
puts "enter your numbers with 'space' between them"
text = gets.chomp
numbers = text.split(" ")
numbers.each do |element|
element.to_i
end
puts alphabetize(numbers)
```

В начале пробовал только цифры, но потом попробовал ввести например "1112 11 22 1222". И сортировка работает не так как ожидал. Отсортированный вывод для такого ввода выглядит как "11 1112 1222 22". Я понял, что сортировка идет просто по каждому элементу в полученном в массив числе, но как быть, если нужно отсортировать именно по величине всего числа, что бы получить желаемое "11 22 1112 1222" - ? Или метод Sort для этого не годится?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь arr.sort!{ |a,b| a.to_i <=> b.to_i }. А вообще советую почитать доки. Хотя бы на русском

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна самая обыкновенная **сортировка по ключу**. В Ruby это [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), этому методу передаётся блок, который принимает элемент коллекции, а возвращает его сортируемый ключ. Такая сортировка будет сравнивать именно возвращённые блоком ключи.

```
["3", "22", "2"].sort_by { |x| x.to_i }
```

...а для таких блоков (которые исключительно вызывают у аргумента некий метод) в Ruby есть особая, сокращённая форма записи через [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc):

```
["3", "22", "2"].sort_by(&:to_i)
```

**Вот так просто.**

Comment: огромное спасибо, теперь ясно!